# Swift 5 + Alamofire 5.*: Decode data with same root object at the top

Tags: ios, swift, codable

My problem is that I have JSON object got from the server like this one:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "at",
            "amount": 446,
            "createdAt": "25/04/2020",
            "updatedAt": "25/04/2020"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "iste",
            "amount": 872,
            "createdAt": "25/04/2020",
            "updatedAt": "25/04/2020"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have Codable struct that decodes this object:

```
struct Expense: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var amount: String
    var createdAt: String
    var updatedAt: String
}
```

Also, I have class with a static method that will do the AF request, also I'm using FuturePromise library for hendling completionof the request:

```
struct RequestAPI {
    @discardableResult
    static func callAndDecode<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> Future<T> {
      return Future(operation: { completion in
          AF.request(route).responseDecodable(decoder: decoder, completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
                switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                      completion(.success(value))
                    case .failure(let error):
                      print(error.localizedDescription)
                      completion(.failure(error))
                }
          })
      })
    }
}
```

Problem is that I have a root "data" parameter that sometimes is present and sometimes not.

I know that there is a solution that I can create a Result codable Model that will be the parent of the Expense Model, but that does not approach that I want, because what will happen if I will have 20 different models I'll have to create 20 deferent root Models?

Yes, I can do it with CodingKeys but that is a little bit hacky and too much of code for this simple task.

So the best approach is to add something like this:

```
struct ExpensesList: Codable {
    var data: [Expense]
}
```

But for me, it is a problem that I will always have 'data' root, so then for any model I will have some 'List' model.

Is there a better approach that is not hacky or this is the only one.

Maybe to send a child model to one data model, but how to recognize it in views,...?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can make your `Root` structure generic, and should also make the `data` property optional.

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let foo: Int
}

struct Bar: Decodable {
    let bar: String
}

struct Root<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: [T]?
}

typealias FooList = Root<Foo>
typealias BarList = Root<Bar>

let fooData = """
{ "data": [ { "foo": 42 } ] }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let barData = """
{ "data": [ { "bar": "baz" } ] }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let foos = try JSONDecoder().decode(FooList.self, from: fooData)
    let bars = try JSONDecoder().decode(BarList.self, from: barData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one approach, that is why I said:

"Maybe to send a child model to one data model, but how to recognize it in views,...?"

But I tried this and it is working very well, but I had some misunderstandings on how to present this data in the view, it's working very well.

Thank you so much.